# Halcon - Goto statement

Tags: goto, halcon

Is there a Goto statement in Halcon? I was not able to find it in the documentation. What I would need is to jump back about 50 lines of code in a certain condition.. Since it happens rarely I'd like to avoid doing it with  a loop. Is there a goto statement or something similar that allows me to jump back to a previous point in the same procedure?

Answer (score 1):

No there is not the GOTO statement.

The reason can be: "Code that relies on goto statements is generally harder to understand and to maintain than code without gotos. Although we are not dogmatic about the matter, it does seem that goto statements should be used rarely, if at all." (Brian Kernighan & Dennis Ritchie, The C Programming Language)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto